# facts.d folder not working as expected

Tags: ansible

Cannot seem to discover facts from facts.d folder. Here is my setup. All the files mentioned are on my OSX machine which has ansible installed. Running playbook against remote machine

file: /work/myproject/ansible.cfg

```
[default]
fact_path=/work/myproject/facts.d
```

file: /work/myproject/facts.d/info.fact (static file)

```
myvar=myvalue
```

command output: ansible --version

```
ansible 2.4.0
  config file = /work/myproject/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = Default w/o overrides
  python version = 2.7.13
```

file: /work/myproject/test.yml (playbook)

```
- name: Testing
  gather_facts: true
  hosts: all
  user: root
  roles:
    - role: test
```

command output: ansible-playbook -i hosts test.yml --limit=dev

```
....
.... 'myvar' is undefined
....
```

Cant seem to use {{myvar}} in tasks like I would expect.

Can anyone spot the problem, or at least suggest some commands/tools to diagnose the problem?

Comment: I made some progress. I am able to access the variable with {{ ansible_local.info.myvar }} . Is this how it is mean to work? I was expecting to be able to access the variable with just {{myvar}} (which is not working)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> All the files mentioned are on my OSX machine which has ansible installed

But `facts.d` directory should be on the **managed host**.

From the [docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#local-facts-facts-d):

> If a **remotely managed system** has an /etc/ansible/facts.d directory, any files in this directory ending in .fact, can be JSON, INI, or executable files returning JSON, and these can supply local facts in Ansible. An alternate directory can be specified using the fact_path play directive.

Update to answer comment:

Documentation excerpt about accessing facts.d facts:

> And this data can be accessed in a template/playbook as: `{{ ansible_local.preferences.general.asdf }}`

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this, you are correct. I had the fact.d folder on the remote machine. I have discovered there is another problem.